# How do I initialize IPython installed using PIP?

Tags: python, pip, ipython

I'm running PepperMint Linux and I've installed IPython using pip but I can't initialize it:

```
$ ipython
bash: /usr/bin/ipython: No such file or directory
```

Although pip says it's correctly installed:

```
$ pip show ipython
---
Name: ipython
Version: 1.2.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

This folder doesn't seem to have any executable files, only source codes:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython
config          core         extensions   frontend.pyc  __init__.pyc  __main__.py   nbformat  scripts    testing
consoleapp.py   display.py   external     html          kernel        __main__.pyc  parallel  sphinxext  utils
consoleapp.pyc  display.pyc  frontend.py  __init__.py   lib           nbconvert     qt        terminal
```

How can I initialize IPython shell? Is it even possible from a pip install, or does pip only download IPython source code?

Comment: Pip should install the entire package. What was the output when you installed via pip? What is your current `PATH`?

Comment: Are any IPython executables present in your Python scripts directory? If so, can you run IPython from that directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the modules were installed under `/usr/local`, then it's likely the ipython script was installed in the same way. So try running:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/ipython
```

If that works, it would seem `/usr/local/bin` is not in your `$PATH` for some reason, so you need to fix that if you want to start ipython without specifying the full path (or you could just create an alias for it).

Comment: Thanks, ipython was on /usr/local/bin/ipython

Comment: By the way, I think it would be better to install pip globally, using the packet manager.